# Facebook Business Login Not working (It looks like this app isn't available)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, fbsdk

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrjrF.png)

I Have implemented facebook SDK for iOS for facebook login but it is providing error as shown in the image attached, I have configured everything but facebook login for business is not working, business verification is also completed but when i put my app on live mode then this issue appears

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this new Facebook login for Business and there're few things I found out to make it work

1. Make sure the permissions you request when login must be the same in the **Configuration** you created

> const loginResult = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
> 'email',
> 'instagram_basic',
> ]);

2. The Facebook Login for business might be available in some regions, for me user in Europe or US can login with facebook when open the in-app browser. But with another region, it'll show "It looks like this app isn't available".
   I'm implementing the Facebook login for business on Android.